# Launching iOS simulator using Appium automation tool

Tags: selenium, webdriver, appium-ios

I am trying to launch iOS app which is developed and built on Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014) using Appium automation tool. In order to launch the ios app i have installed Apple corporate root certificate on IOS simulator by dragging and dropping the cert file over the simulator. Am able to launch the app manually but problem comes when launching app using appium automation tool. IOS app when launched fails and i get "nsurlerrordomain error 1012 iphone" . Below i have attached simple code to set desired capabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "ios");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.3");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
capabilities.setCapability("app","/Path_to_app/XYZ.app");
capabilities.setCapability("no-reset", true);
IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new   URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

How do i set Apple Corp cert through appium tool when launching iOS app on simulator . I tried re-set content and settings but still i face the same issue.

Comment: as far as i know just make your .app file as non enterprise build. It will not asking for any apple certification and make sure in your device UIAutomation is enabled under settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a debug build using valid apple certificate then you don't have to drag and drop the certificate.